# How can I use my own processor module to create a tap in Spring-XD

Tags: spring-xd

I created a stream named `vfs-od-fe-hb`，where the source is `vfs`, the processors are `od` and `fe`, and the sink is `hb`. I want to create a tap in the postion of `fe` and store the result into `hdfs`.

My shell command is:

`stream create --name vfs-od-fe-hb-tap-ib-hdfs --definition "tap:stream:vfs-od-fe-hb.fe > ib > hdfs" --deploy`

`ib` is my processor, it can handle the messages from `fe` successfully, but now the wrong messages:

> Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: XD133E:(pos 34): Expected channel prefix of 'queue' or 'topic' but found 'hdfs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ib` is a processor, the syntax should be

```
tap:stream:vfs-od-fe-hb.fe > ib | hdfs
```

i.e. the tap (named channel) is `ib`'s input channel and we pipe its output as normal.

The parser is reacting to the `> hdfs` because `>` can only be between a named channel and processor or sink.

(or after a processor when sending to a named channel - `queue:...`, `topic:...`).